# Refresh Token call when Access token expired using JWT token

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I am creating two web application in .net core, entity framework db first approach and another web application in .net core only for client side using razor page. My problem is i am keeping my api method as authorize and generating access token and refresh token once user is login. My access token is expired in 20 minutes after that i have to call refresh token silently.I am not getting where to call refresh token so that whenever my access token expired it will call refresh token.

In ajax error block i am calling refresh token, one it will generate new token, then after sleep of 5 second am calling again main method. If status code is 200 then return data.But that method every time returning 401 status code.

```
  error: function (request, textStatus, errorThrown) {
               ErrorHandleFunction(request, textStatus, errorThrown);
               sleep(5000).then(() => {
                    Myfunction();
                });
```

In error when it will go then call the refresh token, after that it will go my function, so that again expiry of access token should be set as 20 minute.Currently it is looping in refresh token call .

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: where to call refresh token so that whenever my access token expired it will call refresh token.@RobertPerry

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement logic to generate refresh tokens yourself in your WebApi. When you make a request to the WebApi you should get a 401 Unauthorized. Maybe a header record to explain that the token has expired? That way you'll know on the front end that you need to call your "RefreshToken" endpoint with your expired token, to get the refresh token.

Here is an example:
https://www.blinkingcaret.com/2018/05/30/refresh-tokens-in-asp-net-core-web-api/